# Unable to clone hyper-ledger fabric on ubuntu

Tags: git

I am trying to clone hyper-ledger onto ubunto. but i am getting the below error.

fatal: unable to access 'http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric/':empty reply from server

Can someone please guide me through this.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get an (useful) answer.

Comment: How did you try to clone it? It works fine.

Comment: Hi axiac,  I clonned it using command: git clone http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric and got the above error.

Comment: It worked just fine for me, using the same command. Maybe there was a connectivity issue when you tried. Try again.